# как Выполнить последовательно

Tags: java, javafx, timeline

Как выполнить последовательно эти два метода? получается что они выполняются одновременно, а нужно чтобы сначала прямоугольник перемещался по оси У а потом по Х

```
public void onClick() throws InterruptedException {

    takeFrom();
    otvodRoll();

}

/**
 * Едем по отводящему рольгангу: шаг 2
 */
public void otvodRoll(){

    // Конечная позиция:
    double stopPositionX = 24;

    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
            // Считаем, сколько времени будет длиться анимация:
            Duration.millis((tube.getLayoutX() - stopPositionX) / 2 * 50),

            event -> {
                logArea.setText(logArea.getText() + "\nПеремещение трубы по отводящему рольгангу окончено");
            },

            // Указываем, какое свойство анимировать, его конечное значение и алгоритм:
            new KeyValue(tube.layoutXProperty(), stopPositionX, Interpolator.LINEAR)
    );

    // Создаем и запускаем одноразовый таймер для анимации по ключевому кадру:
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.delayProperty();

    timeline.play();


}

/**
 * С поперечного транспортера получаем трубу: шаг 1
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public void takeFrom() throws InterruptedException {

    // Конечная позиция:
    double stopPositionY = 78;

    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(

            // Считаем, сколько времени будет длиться анимация:
            Duration.seconds((Math.abs(tube.getLayoutY() - stopPositionY) ) / 13.3),

            event -> {
                logArea.setText("Положили трубу с поперечного транспортера");
            },

            // Указываем, какое свойство анимировать, его конечное значение и алгоритм:
            new KeyValue(tube.layoutYProperty(), stopPositionY, Interpolator.LINEAR)
    );

    // Создаем и запускаем одноразовый таймер для анимации по ключевому кадру:
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(1);
    timeline.play();

}
```

UPD1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените изображение на текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На завершение анимации можно установить [обработчик](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#setOnFinished-javafx.event.EventHandler-). Поэтому достаточно из  метода возвращать `Timeline` и устанавливать этот обработчик в вызывающем методе

```
public Timeline takeFrom() throws InterruptedException {
    ...
    return timeline;
}

public void onClick() throws InterruptedException {
    takeFrom().setOnFinished(event -> otvodRoll());
}
```

или принимать обработчик в качестве аргумента и передавать его из вызывающего метода

```
public void takeFrom(EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler) throws InterruptedException {
    ...
    timeline.setOnFinished(handler);
    timeline.play();
}

public void onClick() throws InterruptedException {
    takeFrom(event -> otvodRoll());
}
```

Лучше даже сделать так, чтобы оба метода могли возвращать [Animation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html) и реализовывали сигнатуру [EventHandler.handle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html#handle-T-), чтобы их можно было объединять в произвольные цепочки.

Comment: Сделал по второму методу: исключение Error:(31, 18) java: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

Comment: takeFrom(() -> otvodRoll());

Comment: Исправил, проверьте.

Comment: простыня вылетела (добавил в UPD)

Comment: Извините, работает

Comment: А как теперь сделать чтоб из последней позиции он уезжал снова вверх?

Comment: По тому же принципу добавить ещё один обработчик, выполняющий ещё одну анимацию. Или использовать циклическую анимацию. Это уже вам виднее.

Comment: не понятно, ведь в takeFrom у нас нет обработчиков

Answer (score 1):

Если сделать так, чтобы методы возвращали `Timeline`:

```
public Timeline takeFrom() {
    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(...);
    return new Timeline(keyFrame);
}

public Timeline otvodRoll() {
    KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(...);
    return new Timeline(keyFrame);
}
```

Тогда можно использовать `SequentialTransition`:

```
SequentialTransition sequence = new SequentialTransition(
    takeFrom(),
    otvodRoll()
);
sequence.play();
```

---

Еще для такого случая, когда нужны только простые передвижения, можно воспользоваться `PathTransition`. Для этого нужно создать путь `Path` от центра прямоугольника до нужных точек и указать этот путь и узел (прямоугольник) в параметрах `PathTransition`. При этом время можно не высчитывать, а задать скорость через метод `setRate()`. Единственное замечание — нужно понимать, что если в исходных примерах анимировалась позиция прямоугольника на панели (`layoutXProperty` и `layoutYProperty`), то `PathTransition` анимирует X и Y в матрице преобразования координат (`translateXProperty` и `translateYProperty`):

```
public void pathAnimation(ActionEvent event) {
    double stopPositionX = 100;
    double stopPositionY = 216;

    double xOffset = tube.getWidth() / 2;
    double yOffset = tube.getHeight() / 2;
    Path path = new Path();
    path.getElements().addAll(
            new MoveTo(xOffset, yOffset),
            new VLineTo(stopPositionY - tube.getLayoutY()),
            new HLineTo(stopPositionX - tube.getLayoutX()));

    PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
    pathTransition.setNode(tube);
    pathTransition.setPath(path);
    // pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
    pathTransition.setRate(0.17);

    pathTransition.setOnFinished(event1 -> {
        System.out.println("Движение закончено");
    });

    pathTransition.play();
}
```